# DocuSign Rest API: upload document to envelope and add document fields for persisting data

Tags: rest, api, field, document, docusignapi

I am using rest API of docusign and I want to know the example of sending fields with document. I just want to send document fields with my each document when sending envelope.

I got below xml with no further example which is not helping. I want some example which includes

mynamemyvalue. However I got only below with API documentation.

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"[http://www.docusign.com/restapi\](http://www.docusign.com/restapi%5C)">

Answer (score 1):

Tabs are always assigned "ownership" to a particular "signer" type Recipient.  You need to add the Tabs to one of the Signers in your envelope. If you just want the data written to the document, i.e. no input UI shown to the signer, set the Tab "Locked" property to "true".

This can be done all at once, i.e. using a POST to the "envelopes" resource and specifying documents, recipients (signers), and tabs.